# Jenkins Pipeline - how does Jenkinsfile tigger docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I have an application which is built on the build server which uses Jenkins Pipeline. I know that the application is built inside the docker container. `Jenkinsfile` in the section `stage('Build')` contains the following line:

```
agent { label 'someDockerImageName' }
```

How can I check what happens under the bonnet, i.e. which docker commands are used ? I guess that there can be used `docker pull` and `docker run`. I haven't found any relevant information on the Jenkins (Console Output, Pipeline Steps).

Comment: `someDockerImageName` image most likely have extended from `jenkins/inbound-agent` image, which if I remember correctly connects to the container over SSH in most cases. It can be different and it depends on the setup. I.E AWS Fargate solution doesn't use SSH I believe it uses HTTP/HTTPS. There might be some useful information here https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent

Comment: You can see the docker commands that Jenkins runs in the console output.  `docker inspect`, `docker run`, etc...  Trying clicking into "view as plain text" if you're not seeing the whole log.

Comment: @kthompso, Console log (view as plain text) contains only the following log: `Running on docker-someid on docker in /home/jenkins/workspace/app_branch`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your [agent syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) is wrong.  Typically in order to use a docker agent in a declarative pipeline, your syntax should be like follows:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'ubuntu'
    }
}
```

Once your pipeline is using a docker agent, you should see the docker commands in the console logs.  For example, here's a simple pipeline and its logging output:

### Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ubuntu'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('foo') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo bar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Logs

```
Started by user Kthompso
Resume disabled by user, switching to high-performance, low-durability mode.
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkinsagent in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . ubuntu
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
jenkinsagent does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1001:1001 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_docker_project@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** ubuntu cat
$ docker top 5f130a2429b6081736a17edf16eef62f4a8fa85cf498f0b338fa8f500ac53d00 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (foo)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo bar
bar
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 5f130a2429b6081736a17edf16eef62f4a8fa85cf498f0b338fa8f500ac53d00
$ docker rm -f 5f130a2429b6081736a17edf16eef62f4a8fa85cf498f0b338fa8f500ac53d00
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```